# Get an array of properties from an array of custom objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop, optimization

I have an array of custom objects, say `Messages`.

These messages have an `identifier`property and I'd like to know what's the most optimal way to get an array of `NSString` from all those `identifiers`.

Right now, I'm just looping through all the objects and putting their id in another array,

```
- (NSArray*)getIdentifiersOf:(NSMutableArray*)array
NSMutableArray *arrIdentifiers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (Message *msg in array){
     [arrIdentifiers addObject:msg.identifier];
}

return (NSArray*)arrIdentifiers;
```

Obviously this works, but it seems so redundant I thought you might think of something else.

I usually just need to send an array of Id's as parameter for example, and I was thinking something along the lines of

```
myArray[@"identifier"]
```

that could automatically use the array but only that specific property for every object inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key:
```

Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

```
NSArray * arrIdentifiers = [array valueForKey:@"identifier"];
```